# Composition of Matrix relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

I am unsure if this exercise is possible to do, could anyone tell me if I am correct or not?

We have DOMAIN {1, 2, 3} and RANGE {1, 2, 3, 4}
and relation R =  {(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)}

The exercise say to find R^2.

I have tried two way to find this.

1. Matrix composition. Here i cam across the problem that you cannot compose a 3x4 matrix with another 3x4
2. Compose the relations themselves what i get is {(1,3) ,(2,4) , (3,?)}

I cant see how i can find the 4 to replace ?

Comment: "I cant see how i can find the 4 to replace ?" You can't, as you've shown! So what does that say about the domain of $R^2$?

Comment: @march i really do not know what i can say about it, maybe that it does not exists?

Comment: The domain absolutely exists: you've shown that there are some numbers you can plug into your function that yield acceptable outputs.  You're very close to the answer here!  What numbers are you allowed to plug into the function, and what numbers are the possible outputs?  That will tell you how to modify your *almost*-correct expression for $R^2$.  Then, once you have it, write an answer to your question below!

Comment: @march can i say that the domain is {1,2}? since we only have (1,3) (2,4). so in a way the range is 3,4?

Comment: I think you've got it!

Comment: @march so i will conclude with that r^2 does not exists for domain {1, 2, 3} but it does for domain {1,2 }?

Comment: I wouldn't put it exactly that way.  I would say that the composition of the relation with itself consists of the set of ordered pairs $\{(1,3),(2,4)\}$, which clearly has domain $\{1,2\}$ and range $\{3,4\}$.

Answer (score 1):

Interpretation 2 is correct (interpretation 1 is not). According to the prescription for $R$,
$$
1\mapsto2\,,~~2\mapsto3\,,~~3\mapsto4\,.
$$
Then, if we compose $R$ with itself, we get$$
1\mapsto2\mapsto3\,,~~2\mapsto3\mapsto4\,,~~3\mapsto4\mapsto\mbox{(nothing)}\,.
$$
That is, in the last spot, since 4 is not in the domain of $R$, we can't plug 3 into $R^2$. Thus, 3 is not in the domain of $R^2$, and the relation $R^2$ is defined by the prescription
$$
R^2:1\mapsto3\,,~~2\mapsto4\,.
$$
In the language of ordered pairs,
$$
R^2=\{(1,3),(2,4)\}\,.
$$
The domain is the set $\{1,2\}$, and the range is the set $\{3,4\}$.